# ParallelMap vs building pure function on the fly

Tags: parallelization

I have a case where one function builds a pure function whenever it is evaluated. A (admittedly contrived) example would be

```
f[l_List] := With[{funStructure = Product[l[[i]]^Slot[i], {i, Length[l]}]},funStructure & @@ l]
```

Using the following code works just fine

```
Map[f[#] &, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
```

However, when I use ParralelMap instead of Map, I get a lot of errors:

```
During evaluation of In[33]:= Function::slot: Slot[i] (in Parallel`Kernels`Private`sendCatch[#1,Parallel`Client`makeDefinitions[Language`DefinitionList[f->{DownValues->{<<2>>}}]]]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.

During evaluation of In[33]:= Function::slot: Slot[i] (in Parallel`Kernels`Private`sendCatch[#1,Parallel`Client`makeDefinitions[Language`DefinitionList[f->{DownValues->{<<2>>}}]]]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.

During evaluation of In[33]:= Function::slot: Slot[i] (in Parallel`Kernels`Private`sendCatch[#1,Parallel`Client`makeDefinitions[Language`DefinitionList[f->{DownValues->{<<2>>}}]]]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.

During evaluation of In[33]:= General::stop: Further output of Function::slot will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[33]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[{Parallel`Protected`neval,(Parallel`Kernels`Private`sendCatch[#1,Parallel`Client`makeDefinitions[Language`DefinitionList[<<1>>->{<<1>>}]]]&)[KernelObject[1,local]]}] returned to top level.

Out[33]= Hold[
 Throw[{Parallel`Protected`neval, \
(Parallel`Kernels`Private`sendCatch[#1, 
       Parallel`Client`makeDefinitions[Language`DefinitionList[\!\(\*
TagBox["f",
HoldForm]\) -> {DownValues -> {HoldPattern[f[l_List]] :> 
              With[{funStructure = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i\), \(Length[l]\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(l[[i]]\), \(Slot[i]\)]\)}, (funStructure &) @@ l], 
             HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 
              With[{funStructure = x #1}, (funStructure &)[
                x]]}}]]] &)["KernelObject"[1, "local"]]}]]
```

Is there anything to be said besides "you should not be using such a function definition anyway!!!" :).

Mma Version Number is 11.1.1.0

Comment: There seems to be a pure function being wrapped around your definition somewhere during the evaluation of `ParallelMap` (I don't have time to check where exactly at the moment). Since your `Slot[...]` expression is not wrapped inside `Function`, the evaluation of that pure function tries to replace the `Slot[...]` expression with the appropriate expression, but fails due to the index being `i` and not a number. You can circumvent this by "hiding" `Slot[…]` from `Function`, using e.g. `Slot@@{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Workaround

To work around the issue, simply "hide" the `Slot[…]` expression using `Slot@@{…}`:

```
f[l_List] := With[{funStructure = Product[l[[i]]^Slot@@{i}, {i, Length[l]}]},funStructure& @@ l]
```

### Fix

While the above workaround is easy, a more permanent solution would be nice. The following code achieves this by fixing the underlying problem:

```
ParallelMap;
DownValues@Parallel`Protected`kernelEvaluate =
  DownValues@Parallel`Protected`kernelEvaluate /. {
    sc_[#, cmd_] & :> Function[link, sc[link, cmd]]
  };
```

### The underlying problem

As I mentioned in the comments, the issue is that the definitions are wrapped in another `Function` at some point. Since the `Slot[…]` is not inside a `Function` head at that point, the outer function attempts to replace the `Slot[…]` expression with a value (with fails of course). We can see this on the following example:

```
buildFunc = Hold@With[{s = Slot[1]}, s &]
(* Hold[With[{s = #1}, s &]] *)

applyFunc[f_, arg_] := ReleaseHold[f][arg]

applyFunc[buildFunc, 3]
(* 3 *)

With[{f = buildFunc}, f &@4]
(* Hold[With[{s = 4}, s &]] *)

applyFunc[With[{f = buildFunc}, f &@4], 3]
(* 4 *)
```

As you can see, the `Slot[…]` expression was replaced by `4` in the second example.

### How the fix works

The fix above works by patching the offending definition of `` Parallel`Protected`kernelEvaluate `` (which in this case is used to push the definitions of symbols to the parallel kernels). The patch replaces the `Function` with unnamed arguments with a version with named arguments. This prevents the "unprotected" `Slot[…]` expressions in `cmd` from being replaced, fixing the issue.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. A very direct way to see the problem is `Function/@Downvalues[f]`